# Градиент на фоновое изображение в Css

Tags: html, css, css3

Добрый день возник вопрос... Возможно ли применить градиент на фоновую картинку (background-image: url(img/bg.png); от 10% не прозрачности до 100% не прозрачности? )[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

На картинку нельзя. Но можно наложить поверх абсолютно позиционированный блок с градиентом от непрозрачного белого до прозрачного.
Хотя если и так на фоне картинка, лучшее ее в ФШ отредактировтаь.

Comment: Подобного рода советы принято давать в комментариях: они указывают направление, куда двигаться дальше, но не дают исчерпывающий ответ на вопрос. Если бы в вашем тексте был пример с исходником (вот прям возьмите картинку из вопроса и создайте в ответе сниппет), то да, это был бы ответ. А так - "не является ответом на вопрос".

Answer (score 0):

Такой способ не будет работать в ie и edge

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: url(https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/1_IlAqhBPauoUpoNNJAb4qePo35x34flH=w1366-h613-iv1), linear-gradient(45deg, white, transparent);
  background-blend-mode: overlay;
}
```